# Background Worker reporting multiple percentages

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I'd like my background worker to report progress for both individual tasks and the total progress.
Any suggestions how i'd get multiple values over to backgroundworker_ProgressChanged?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `userState` object of the [`ReportProgress` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3zbdb1t.aspx) could be used for passing arbitrary objects to the [`ProgressChanged` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx).